# shopify run from a 3rd party hosting website like iPage

Tags: email, web, hosting, shopify, web-hosting

I have a shop currently running on shopify, but I brought the web domain myself, not through shopify, thus shopify doesn't allow me to make a website email account i.e. admin@mywebsitename.com .

I decided to purchased an iPage.com plan to make the website email address (admin@mywebsitename.com).

I am being instructed to repoint my website to new name servers but I'm afraid that will disrupt my shop.

Can anyone help me with how do i make a website email (admin@mywebsitename.com) with ipage.com, without disrupting my shopify shop.

all your help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your MX entry is like this.

[image: MX Entries]

Then do to your advanced DNS settings and change your mail entry from CNAME to A record and then put the IP address of your mail server.

[image: Change DNS Settings]

Comment: can you explain in greater detail please? the whole process if you can.

thanks for the help